# Is tap water in Moscow safe to drink?

Tags: health, russia, tap-water, moscow

I will be travelling to Moscow, Russia and I want to fill my water bottle at my accommodation (no built-in filters). I have been hearing some myths that this tap water is unclean and unsafe to drink.

Is this true? Is the tap water safe to drink in Moscow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t have any scientific studies or anything like that to back this up, but second-hand experience: my wife is from (and currently lives in) Moscow.

Neither she nor any of her family/friends drink tap water unless there’s a filter installed. It’s not so bad that you’re likely to end up in hospital after taking a sip, but drinking unfiltered tap water is generally avoided and considered unwise.

Comment: It also tastes pretty awful usually.